# Solving the wave equation for a circular membrane in polar cordinates

Tags: python, finite-difference, numerics, wave-propagation, laplacian

[image: Modo m=0 n=1]

As you see this mode is not right, unless for what i understand

And the initial conditions were

```
kth_zero = jn_zeros(0, 1)  # Obtiene el primer cero de la función de Bessel de orden 0
Z = np.cos(phi) * jv(1, kth_zero * R / radio)  # Utiliza el primer cero para J_0
u[0, :, :] = Z.T# conidición incial para tiempo 0
#u[1, :, :] = Z.T
```

[image: Mode 11]

```
kth_zero = jn_zeros(1, 1)  # Obtiene el primer cero de la función de Bessel de orden 0
Z = np.cos(phi) * jv(1, kth_zero * R / radio)  # Utiliza el primer cero para J_0
u[0, :, :] = Z.T# conidición incial para tiempo 0
```

Hello everyone I know that a similar question was answered ten years ago, but I have a few issues with my code based on this [How can I solve wave equation for circular membrane in polar coordinates?](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/20279/how-can-i-solve-wave-equation-for-circular-membrane-in-polar-coordinates) question.

I tried to change the normal modes with the initial condition:

Does anyone know how it works?

My code is the following

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import jv, jn_zeros
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

#%% Variables

Nr= 50
Nphi=50
T=1000
radio=5
c=1
#%% Steps
dr=5/50
dphi=2*np.pi/Nphi
dt=1/T

#%% Vectors

r=np.linspace( 0 , radio , Nr  )
phi=np.linspace( 0 , 2*np.pi , Nphi )

#%% Meshgrid

R, phi = np.meshgrid( r , phi  )
X = R*np.cos(phi) # pasamos a cartesianas para el plot
Y = R*np.sin(phi) # pasamos a cartesianas para el plot

# Wave vector

u=np.zeros( ( T , Nr , Nphi ) )

#%% Initial condition 

kth_zero = jn_zeros(2, 1)[0]  # Obtiene el primer cero de la función de Bessel de orden 2
Z = np.cos(phi) * jv(2, kth_zero * R / radio)  # Utiliza el primer cero para J2
u[0, :, :] = Z.T
u[1, :, :] = Z.T

#%%
# Create a 3D plot of initial condition
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
Z = u[0]

ax.plot_surface(R, phi, Z, cmap='viridis')
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
plt.show()
#%%Stepping

k1 = c*dt**2/dr**2
for t in range(2, T-1): # empieza en dos por como son las condiciones iciales
    for i in range(0, Nr-1):
        for j in range(0, Nphi-1):
            ri = max(r[i], 0.5*dr)  # To avoid the singularity at r=0
            k2 = c*dt**2/(2*ri*dr)
            k3 = c*dt**2/(dphi*ri)**2
            u[t+1, i, j] = 2*u[t, i, j] - u[t-1, i, j] \
            + k1*(u[t, i+1, j] - 2*u[t, i, j] + u[t, i-1, j])\
            + k2*(u[t, i+1, j] - u[t, i-1, j])\
            + k3*(u[t, i, j+1] - 2*u[t, i, j] + u[t, i, j-1])

        u[t+1, i, -1] = u[t+1, i, 0]  # Update the values for phi=2*pi

#%%
# Create a 3D plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
Z = u[999]  # Or choose another time step to visualize

ax.plot_surface(X.T, Y.T, Z, cmap='viridis')
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
plt.show()

#%% Countor plot
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.contour(X.T, Y.T, Z)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
```

I also added this to my code in order to create a 3d animation

```
#%% # Create a 3D plot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

line= ax.plot_surface(X.T,Y.T,u[0])

def animate(i,Z,line):
    Z=u[i]
    ax.clear()
    line=ax.plot_surface(X.T,Y.T,Z)
    return line,
# Setting the axes properties
ax.set_xlim([-5.0, 5.0])
ax.set_xlabel('X')

ax.set_ylim([-5.0, 5.0])
ax.set_ylabel('Y')

ax.set_zlim([-400, 400])
ax.set_zlabel('Z')


# Reduce the number of frames and adjust the frame interval for faster animation
num_frames = 2000  # Set the number of frames you want to show
frame_interval = 2  # Adjust this value to control the animation speed

# Create the animation
ani = FuncAnimation(
    fig, animate,  fargs=(Z, line),frames=num_frames, interval=frame_interval, repeat=True, blit=False
)
plt.show()


kth_zero = jn_zeros(1, 1)  # 
Z = np.cos(phi) * jv(1, kth_zero * R / radio)  # 
u[0, :, :] = Z.T
```

But they seem to not correspond to the circular normal modes[image: Circular normal modes]

Comment: Welcome to Scicomp.SE. I just ran your code and obtained a result that looks like a mode.

Comment: Can you post some images or results showing what you are getting and how it compares to what you expect?

Comment: Hello everyone.  Yes, I am going to update some images. Regarding to answer of nicoguaro,  my problem is that I do not know how to generate different modes. I have changed the values of the initial condition and I do not get different modes.

Comment: I think that you have some issues with the roots of Bessel functions. Have you tried presenting analytical solutions before using a numerical method? I have some snippets [here](https://gist.github.com/nicoguaro/3c6f759888be2b029c26#file-circular_membrane-py).

Comment: Hi, I just solved the problem, whenever I can I will update the code and the images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the initial conditions and how I was understanding them.

The problem was the following. When you are solving the differential equation for the wave propagation on a circular membrane the initial condition is:
$$\sum_{m=0}\sum_{n=1}A_{mn}J_m(k_{mn}r)\cos(m\theta+\delta_m)$$

So when m=0 the $\cos0*\theta=1$. This was not taken into account in the code, so when I was trying to solve mode 01, the term $\cos\theta$ was still there. Another thing that I changed (but is not needed) was to eliminate this `#T[1, :, :] = Z.T` because it is redundant and I start the code with `t=1`, not `t=2`. Finally, in the loop iteration, I start from `t+1`. This is because it was the way I learned to compute finite difference. Also, this is the link where I obtained the finite difference version of the cylindrical Laplacian.

[https://www.math.arizona.edu/~leonk/papers/polarFD7.pdf](https://www.math.arizona.edu/%7Eleonk/papers/polarFD7.pdf)

Here is the fixed code.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.special import jv, jn_zeros
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation, PillowWriter

#%% Parameters
Nr = 50
N_phi = 50
N_steps = 200
radius = 1
c = 10
dphi = 2*np.pi/N_phi
dr = 5./Nr
dt = 0.0001
CFL=c**2*dt/min(dr,dphi)
print(CFL)



#%% Initial conditions
r = np.linspace(0, radius, Nr)
phi = np.linspace(0, 2*np.pi, N_phi)
R, phi = np.meshgrid(r, phi)
X = R*np.cos(phi)
Y = R*np.sin(phi)
#%% Modos Simples
m=0
n=1
kth_zero = jn_zeros(m, n)[n-1]
Z = np.cos(m*phi) * jv(m, kth_zero*R/radius)
u = np.zeros((N_steps, Nr, N_phi))
u[0, :, :] = Z.T/10

#%% Plot de combinación inicial
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
M = u[0]  # Or choose another time step to visualize

ax.plot_surface(X.T, Y.T, M, cmap='viridis')
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
plt.show()
#%% Stepping
k1 = (c*dt)**2/dr**2
for t in range(0, N_steps-1):
    for i in range(0, Nr-1):
        for j in range(0, N_phi-1):
            ri = max(r[i], 0.5*dr)  # To avoid the singularity at r=0
            k2 = (c*dt)**2/(2*ri*dr)
            k3 = (c*dt)**2/(dphi*ri)**2
            u[t+1, i, j] = 2*u[t, i, j] - u[t-1, i, j] \
            + k1*(u[t, i+1, j] - 2*u[t, i, j] + u[t, i-1, j])\
            + k2*(u[t, i+1, j] - u[t, i-1, j])\
            + k3*(u[t, i, j+1] - 2*u[t, i, j] + u[t, i, j-1])

        u[t+1, i, -1] = u[t+1, i, 0]  # Update the values for phi=2*pi

#%% Plot 11
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')
Z = u[90]  # Or choose another time step to visualize # Crece hasta 150 maximo en 610
# Recien en 900 empieza a cambiar el sentido
ax.plot_surface(X.T, Y.T, Z, cmap='viridis')
ax.set_xlabel('X')
ax.set_ylabel('Y')
ax.set_zlabel('Z')
plt.show()
```

[image: Mode 0 1]

Well, I figured out how to perform the animation and given the periodicity of the wave propagation, `Nsteps` must be 2000.

```
#%%

fig = plt.figure()
ax3d = fig.add_subplot(111, projection='3d')

# Inicializa la superficie 3D
Z_3d = u[0]
surf = [ax3d.plot_surface(X.T, Y.T, Z_3d, cmap='viridis')]
# Set Z-axis limits
ax3d.set_zlim(-150, 150)
# Función de actualización para la animación
def update(i):
    Z_3d = u[i]  # Datos para la iteración actual
    surf[0].remove()  # Elimina la superficie anterior
    surf[0] = ax3d.plot_surface(X.T, Y.T, Z_3d, cmap='viridis')  # Actualiza el gráfico 3D

    ax3d.set_xlabel('X')
    ax3d.set_ylabel('Y')
    ax3d.set_zlabel('Z')


ani = FuncAnimation(fig, update, frames=len(u), interval=1, blit=False, repeat=False)
# Set the view angle (azimuth and elevation)
ax3d.view_init(azim=70, elev=13)

plt.show()


#%%


# Specify the filename for the GIF
gif_filename = 'animationmode11.gif'

# Save the animation as a GIF using PillowWriter
ani.save("your_animation.gif", writer="pillow", fps=30, dpi=80)

plt.show()
```

The gift is too big, so believe me that it is working.

Comment: Can you describe what the problem was?

Comment: For sure. The problem was the following. When you are solving the differential equation for the wave propagation on a circular membrane the initial condition is the following. $$\sum_{m=0}\sum_{n=1}A_{mn}J_m(k_{mn}r)cos(m\theta+\delta_m)$$.   So when m=0 the $cos0*\theta=1$. This was not taken into account  in the code, so when I was trying to solve the mode 01, the term $cos\theta$ was still there.

Comment: Another thing that I changed (but is not needed) was to eliminate this #T[1, :, :] = Z.T because it is redundant and I start the code with t=1, not t=2. Finally, in the loop iteration, I start from t+1.

Comment: Please, add those details to the answer so it can help other members of the community or another person in the future.